# Spring5 hibernate template's findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam method's alternative

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

Till now,I used findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam in Spring HibernateTemplate for handling namedqueries. [Spring5 deprecated this method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/HibernateTemplate.html#findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-)..

In future it might get removed, What are the alternative solutions to findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam?
Please help me in this regard..

Example:

```
public Child getChildByNameWithToys(String childName) {
  return (Child) getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam(
    Child.Constants.FIND_CHILD_BY_NAME_QUERY,
    Child.Constants.CHILD_NAME_PARAM, childName).get(0);
 }
```

Comment: Have a look at the javadocs:
Deprecated. as of 5.0.4, in favor of a custom HibernateCallback lambda code block passed to the general execute(org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateCallback<T>) method https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/HibernateOperations.html#findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-

Comment: @MateuszMrozewski   i didn't quite get you.. please explain it..

Comment: Usually when method gets deprecated javadocs mention the alternative (if the project is well documented). So if you go to the javadocs you mentioned it says "Description copied from interface: HibernateOperations". Click on HibernateOperations and see the description provided. You should have a look at HibernateCallback

Answer (score 3):

The above code should be changed to use HibernateCallback like below.

```
public Child getChildByNameWithToys(String childName) {
    List<Child> list = getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback<List<Child>>() {
        public List<Child> doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException {
            return getSession().getNamedQuery(Child.Constants.FIND_CHILD_BY_NAME_QUERY)
                    .setParameter(Child.Constants.CHILD_NAME_PARAM, childName)
                    .list();
        }
    });

    if (list != null && list.size() > 0)
        return list.get(0);
    else return null;
}
```